# Excel graph force the Row / Columns from data source

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies, the Title is slightly misleading.  Rather than switch the row/column (select a graph, then on the design tab, click "Switch Row/Column") in excel, I would like to force it initially, mitigating the need to change.

My code is as below, adding another column the rows/columns have switched automatically:

```
Sub InsertBar(rngToPrint As Range, lngTopleft As String, BottomLeft As String)
    Dim strRange As String
    Dim rngChart As Range
    Dim myChart As Chart

    lngStartRow = Sheets(rngToPrint.Worksheet.Name).Range(lngTopleft).Row
    lngEndRow = Sheets(rngToPrint.Worksheet.Name).Range(BottomLeft).Row

    Sheets(rngToPrint.Worksheet.Name).Activate
    'Correct
    'Sheets(rngToPrint.Worksheet.Name).Range("$A$" & CStr(lngStartRow) & ":$D$" & CStr(lngEndRow)).Select

    'Shows Flipped Axis
    Sheets(rngToPrint.Worksheet.Name).Range("$A$" & CStr(lngStartRow) & ":$E$" & CStr(lngEndRow)).Select

    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, 500, 10, , 175).Chart

    With myChart
        .ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = rngToPrint.Worksheet.Name & " Receiving Sim Stats - (Today Only)"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("B" & lngStartRow - 1).Value
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = Range("C" & lngStartRow - 1).Value
        .SeriesCollection(3).Name = Range("D" & lngStartRow - 1).Value

    'Dataseries which has just been added
        .SeriesCollection(4).Name = Range("E" & lngStartRow - 1).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tom, I many times get help from Excel itself. I start a macro recording, perform manually the actions I would like to program and stop the recording. Then, there is a module created by Excel that contains all the code that is invoked to programmatically perform what I did manually. I guess that if you try it, you will get the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else interested, the answer I found in the end was this:

```
    With myChart
        .PlotBy = xlColumns
```

Or if you would like to switch this the other way:

```
myChart.PlotBy = xlRows
```